# ADO organization directory issue

Tags: azure-devops

We have a scenario where we need to use ADO connector in MS Flow .But the MS Flow was not able to identify/connect to the ADO organization because it has connected with a different directory sample.onmicrosoft.com instead of microsoft.onmicrosoft.com.
Can any one please suggest what can we do in these cases .

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Microsoft Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/), you will sign in with account and specify its AD domain, such as Microsoft. And then you can only connect to Azure DevOps organizations which connect to the same AD domain.

Therefore, there are 2 workarounds for your issue, you could either sign in using account which lies in directory `sample.onmicrosoft.com`, and then try to connect this target Azure DevOps organization. You could go to [Azure DevOps profile page](https://aex.dev.azure.com/go/profile/?campaign=o%7Emsft%7Eold%7Evsts%7Eprofile) and switch to this AD domain.
[image]

The other way is to change the AD domain to `microsoft.onmicrosoft.com` for this target organization by following this doc: [Change your organization connection to another Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-azure-ad-connection?view=azure-devops).

Comment: As per workaround 1 we cant login to flow with account which lies in directory sample.onmicrosoft.com because we still  need some custom connectors which lies in Microsoft account .Is there any alternative for azure devops connector itself?

Comment: Currently we don't find alternative for Azure DevOps connector itself. You could submit this feedback here: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Connecting-To-Data/bd-p/ConnectingToData, which is professional channel for related product group to handle MS flow connectors issues.